# Can't open a file inside a google test

Tags: c++, googletest, bazel

I have a file in the same directory as the test.
Since I'm using Bazel as the build system (in Linux) I don't have to create the main and initialize the tests (In fact I don't know where the main function resides when using Bazel).

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
//Other include files
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

TEST(read_file_test, read_file) {
    std::string input_file("file_path");
    graph gr;
    graph_loader loader;

    ASSERT_TRUE(loader.load(gr, input_file));
}
```

The BUILD file for the tests:

```
cc_test(
    name = "loaderLib_test",
    srcs = ["loaderLib_test.cpp"],
    deps = [
        "//src/lib/loader:loaderLib",
        "@com_google_googletest//:gtest_main",
    ],
    data = glob(["resources/tests/input_graphs/graph_topology/**"]),
)
```

The WORKSPACE file:

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:git.bzl", "git_repository")

git_repository(
    name = "com_google_googletest",
    remote = "https://github.com/google/googletest",
    tag = "release-1.8.1",
)
```

The directory structure:

```
.
├── README.md
├── WORKSPACE
├── bazel-bin -> /home/mmaghous/.cache/bazel/_bazel_mmaghous/35542ec7cbabc2e6f7475e3870a798d1/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin
├── bazel-graph_processor -> /home/mmaghous/.cache/bazel/_bazel_mmaghous/35542ec7cbabc2e6f7475e3870a798d1/execroot/__main__
├── bazel-out -> /home/mmaghous/.cache/bazel/_bazel_mmaghous/35542ec7cbabc2e6f7475e3870a798d1/execroot/__main__/bazel-out
├── bazel-testlogs -> /home/mmaghous/.cache/bazel/_bazel_mmaghous/35542ec7cbabc2e6f7475e3870a798d1/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/testlogs
├── resources
│   └── tests
│       └── input_graphs
│           ├── graph_data
│           │   └── G1_data.txt
│           └── graph_topology
│               ├── G1_notFully_notWeakly.txt
│               ├── G2_notFully_Weakly.txt
│               ├── G3_fully_weakly.txt
│               ├── G4_fully_weakly.txt
│               ├── G5_notFully_weakly.txt
│               ├── G6_notFully_weakly.txt
│               └── G7_notFully_notWeakly.txt
├── src
│   ├── lib
│   │   ├── algorithms
│   │   │   ├── BUILD
│   │   │   └── graph_algorithms.hpp
│   │   ├── graph
│   │   │   ├── BUILD
│   │   │   └── graph.hpp
│   │   └── loader
│   │       ├── BUILD
│   │       └── graph_loader.hpp
│   └── main
│       ├── BUILD
│       └── main.cpp
├── tests
│   ├── BUILD
│   ├── algorithmsLib_test.cpp
│   ├── graphLib_test.cpp
│   └── loaderLib_test.cpp
└── todo.md
```

So how should I reference the file if it's in the same folder as the test or any other folder?

BTW: Using the full path from the root of my file systems works fine.

Comment: I believe your looking for the data attribute - https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/build-ref.html#data

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @tangy, I added the data dependencies but still, I couldn't open it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the glob is relative to the BUILD file like when you refer a file in srcs. The glob is expanding to an empty list because no file is matching. The easiest way to see it is putting the full path explicitly instead of the glob and Bazel will complain.
You have two options, or you move the resources folder inside the tests folder or you create a BUILD file in the resources folders where you create a filegroup exposing the txt files and then in the test target you reference the filegroup target.
https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/general.html#filegroup

In **resources/BUILD**

```
filegroup(
    name = "resources",
    srcs = glob(["tests/input_graphs/graph_topology/**"]),
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

In **tests/BUILD**

```
cc_test(
    name = "loaderLib_test",
    srcs = ["loaderLib_test.cpp"],
    deps = [
        "//src/lib/loader:loaderLib",
        "@com_google_googletest//:gtest_main",
    ],
    data = ["//resources"],
)
```

Comment: Can you post the BUILD file and the location respective to the WORKSPACE file? If you go to the bazel-bin and in the folder named <target_name>.runfiles you can see inside the __main__ folder if it is copied there and with which path. It has to be relative to this path.

Comment: I tried to include all info you will need.

Comment: And how are you referring the file inside the test? It should be relative path to the root of the workspace. In this case `resources/tests/input_graphs/graph_topology/G1_notFully_notWeakly.txt`

Comment: I tried that but I still can't open the file.

For your information when I added the files directly to the folder containing the tests, with `data = glob(["**"])` and referencing the file with `file_path = "tests/file_name.txt"` I was able to read the files.

Comment: The problem is the glob that will not work because resources is one folder up. I updated the answer on how you can do it.

Comment: Okey thanks @limdor, that helped, maybe you want to mention in the answer that you should set the visibility to `public` in the `file_group`, if the resources are outside the `test` folder

Comment: Another tip for debugging globs: `bazel query --output=build //resources/...` will expand the globs. Setting `allow_empty=False` in the `glob` will also make the failure to match an error, rather than waiting for the test to fail.